# End kGAISessionControl in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I want to use Google Analytics v3.13 in my iOS app in Swift. It is internet radio player. I need to know approximately how many listeners I have from my app.

I use this code to add event when user starts listening (for example hits play button):

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("shoutcast_events", action: "listening", label: nil, value: nil)
tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: "start")
tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: nil)
```

And when user stops listening (for example hits stop button) I use this:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("shoutcast_events", action: "listening", label: nil, value: nil)
tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: "end")
tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: nil)
```

When I press play, event is added to Analytics, but when I press stop, event is still there. I want it to be removed. Event disappears afrer about 5 minutes even if i don't click stop.

What I'm doing wrong? How to do it? Maybe is there a better solution? :)

Comment: Have you already found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not…